# Number of patterns

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A pattern consist of three non-empty strings $s_1$ , $s_2$ , $s_3$ such that no string is prefix of another. Strings can have length $\leq n$ and consist of first $k$ english letters of the alphabet.

What is total number of such patterns for given value of $n$ and $k$

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! To get the best answers, learn the most, and preventing people form giving hints you already know, it is necessary to include your attempt. You can edit your question to include this.

Comment: It's also polite to add a question mark at the end of the question

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274374/finding-out-this-combination